# Uploading image error

Tags: php, debugging, image-processing, error-handling

Hey folks, im trying to get an image to upload to the specified directory and all im getting as an output is 'There was an error uploading the file, please try again!'

```
$upload_dir = "blog/wp-content/uploads/products";    
if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
    echo "Directory exists and is fine....";
}
else {
    echo "Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.";
}

$target_path = "blog/wp-content/uploads/products/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should also check the upload status in `$_FILES['image_file']['error']` [(php.net docs)](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) This error code may indicate what is the cause of failure

Comment: You really should not keep the original filename. Imagine someone uploading a php file, your webserver will gladly run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not receive an warning, this is the only reason: `If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.` an quote from the documentation.

Check the upload using [.is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php).